# javascript access to items in a table

Tags: javascript, templates

I have a table which I want to calculate sum of a column in javascript any time there is a change.

I tried this but does not work:
Html template:

```
 <form method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr class="heading">
                    <td>
                        Item
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        Price
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <div id="itemstable">
                    {% if items|length > 0 %}
                        {% for item in items %}
                            <tr class="item">
                                <td>
                                    <input id="{{ item.id }}" name="items-{{ item.id }}-amount" required="" type="text" value="{{ item.description }}" >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="amount-{{ item.id }}" name="items-{{ item.id }}-amount" required="" type="number" min="0"  value="{{ item.amount }}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <tr class="item">
                            <div>
                            <td>
                                <input id={{ items|length }} name="description-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="{{form.description}}">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id=amount-{{ items|length }} name="amount-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="{{form.amount}}">
                            </td>
                                </div>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr class="total">
                    <td>
                        Total:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input id="total" type="text" value="00.00"readonly>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


<script>
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"), sumVal = 0;
    console.log(table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML);
    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {

        sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =  sumVal;
    console.log(sumVal);

    </script>
```

To understand the issue" sumVal equal to NaN

So I tried too understand possible issue and in log with `console.log(table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML);`

I have this in console:

```
<input id="amount-1" name="items-1-amount" required="" type="number" min="0" value="1.0">
```

So to seems not getting the value of the row but the html input...

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value`.

The type of your price input in if block is "number". I think that's a mistake too.